Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^n=[a_{ij}(n)]$. Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}$
Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^n=[a_{ij}(n)]$. Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}$$
My Attempt
$[a_{ij}(2)]=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 2\\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$
$[a_{ij}(3)]=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix} 12 & 5\\ 5 & 2\end{pmatrix}$
$[a_{ij}(4)]=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^4=\begin{pmatrix} 29 & 12\\ 12 & 5\end{pmatrix}$
I observe that we are dealing with the sequence $0,1,2,5,12,29,70...$ whose $n^{th}$ term can be described as
$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ .
But after this I can't proceed .
The answer given is $\sqrt{2}+1$

Diagonalization!

I think if $r(n) = \frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}$, then $r(n+1) = \frac{2 r(n) + 1}{r(n)}$.  From there, you could solve it as a typical problem of iterating a function and finding the limit (though this is one of the more complex cases where the terms alternate above and below the limit, so the typical argument would involve taking the subsequences of even and odd terms, where one of them increases to the limit and the other decreases to the limit).

The solution to $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ is $a_n=\dfrac{(\color{orange}{1+\sqrt2})^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n}{2\sqrt2}$

This answer is about the recurrence relation where you hit a deadend
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$
Using Generating functions;
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\underset{n\to n+2}\implies a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+a_{n}$$
$$Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}x^n=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$
$$Q(x)=\frac{x(2a_0-a_1)-a_1}{x^2+2x-1}$$
$$a_0=0,a_1=1$$
$$Q(x)=-\frac{1+x}{x^2+2x-1}=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{x+1+\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{x+1-\sqrt2}\right]$$
Writing the Taylor series for the two expressions and finding our closed form for $a_n$, we get the following result (verify using the below links)
$$\boxed{a_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n}{2\sqrt2}}$$
reference1
reference2
reference3
If this seems too boring, you can try the Characteristic Equation method (linked below) , it may be the easier alternative to this answer.

If you are interested in learning about recurrence relations you can check our this and this

Now from the above boxed result,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}=\frac{1,2,5,12,29,\cdots}{0,1,2,5,12,29,\cdots}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt2)^{n}-(1-\sqrt2)^{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1+\sqrt2)-(1-\sqrt2)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt2}{1+\sqrt2}\right)^{n}}{1-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt2}{1+\sqrt2}\right)^{n}}$$
using this
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{12}(n)}{a_{22}(n)}=\sqrt2+1}$$

First observe that $A^n\cdot(0,1) = (a_{12}(n),a_{22}(n)) = (a_{n+1},a_n)$, where $a_{n} = 2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ and $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 0$.
The ratio $\lim a_{12}(n)/a_{22}(n)$ is therefore equal to the ratio $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$.
When a linear recurrence has distinct eigenvalues ($|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|>\dots|\lambda_m|$) (in this case $1\pm\sqrt{2}$) it can be written in the form $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{m} A_i\lambda_i^n$.
Let $k$ be the smallest $i$, such that $A_k \neq 0, \lambda_k \neq 0$, then:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{A_k\lambda_k^n + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} A_i\lambda_i^n}{A_k\lambda_k^{n-1}+\sum_{i=k+1}^{m} A_i\lambda_i^{n-1}} = \frac{A_k\lambda_k + \sum_{i=k+1}^{m} A_i\lambda_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_k}\right)^{n-1}}{A_k+\sum_{i=k+1}^{m} A_i\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_k}\right)^{n-1}}
\end{align}
As $|\lambda_k| > |\lambda_i|$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\lambda_k/\lambda_i)^{n-1} = 0$, so taking the limit of both sides we get:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{A_k\lambda_k}{A_k} = \lambda_k
$$
(In general we get that the limit is the eigenvalue with biggest magnitude which occurs in the explicit solution of the recurrence).
In our case $\lambda_1 = 1+\sqrt{2}, \lambda_2 = 1-\sqrt{2}$, which satisfies this condition. As $1-\sqrt{2} < 0$ (and our ratio is clearly positive) the answer must be $1+\sqrt{2}$.
